# setcookie() do not set value in chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies

hi all i am facing problem with `setcookie()` in chrome only. It is working fine in firefox.
this is my function where i am using cookie

```
 function step3($voice_choice = null)
 {
    if (!empty($voice_choice)) 
    {
        setcookie("voice_choice", $voice_choice, time() + 2000, "/");
    }
 }
```

when I print $_COOKIE output is

```
   Array ( [CAKEPHP] => s247c7mlagt5am6h323cm7pqj0 [voice_choice] => favicon.ico )
```

the value of `voice_choice` is not what i set in above function.

Comment: Maybe it's a browser's configuration issue, the don't always accept cookies and maybe the path you are putting is related. Have you tried another webkit browser such as Safari?

Comment: show the code that you use to call `step3()`

Comment: there is a link in .ctp file which call step3().

<?php echo $html->link("FEMALE", array('controller' => 'survey', 'action' => "step3/female"),array("class"=>"option_image"));?>


            <?php echo $html->link("MALE", array('controller' => 'survey', 'action' => "step3/male"),array("class"=>"option_image"));?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using CakePHP why not do it their way?

```
public $components = array('Cookie');

$cookieTime = '8 weeks';  //The amount of time you want the cookie to last

if ( !empty($voice_choice) )
  this->Cookie->write('voice_choice', $voice_choice, true, $cookieTime);
```

Also for debugging cookies a nice trick in Chrome is:

Inspect Element -> Resources Tab -> Cookies -> yoursite (local.yoursite.com) to see if the cookie is being written.

Comment: Brett Stewart .. I used CakePHP cookie first and there was same problem with CakePHP cookie too.

Comment: In your core.php located /app/Config/core.php try setting

Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);
Configure::write('Session.ini',array('session.cookie_secure' => false, 'session.referer_check' => false));

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thank you Brett Stewart.. let me check it first and then i will let you know